# baffled as to why faraday is giving me a 403 error

Tags: ruby, faraday

I'm using Faraday to interact with an API. It is returning large JSON objects (> 10MB) but not that large. When I dump the res.body, it is:

```
{"code": 403, "error": "Exceeded max response data size"}
```

What is going on? Code isn't presumably an http status and I've never had a response be too large. Can I adjust the data size?

Comment: Does Faraday have a tuneable max-accept limit?

Comment: I don't think so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error sounds like a response from the API you're querying, rather than an issue with Faraday specifically. I would not expect Faraday to overwrite the actual HTTP response body.

What happens when you make the API request using `curl -i`?

If it is caused by Faraday struggling with the large response payload, can you just stream the response directly to disk?